# Azure Powershell command for getting resources in a Resource Group

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

In the Azure Powershell version 0.8 and 0.9, there is command

```
Get-AzureResource -ResourceGroupName "RGName" -OutputObjectFormat New
```

And, It returns the resources in the mentioned Resource Group of Azure. It necessitates the azure mode to be ARM mode.

But, in the Azure PowerShell version 1.2 and above

```
Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceGroupName "RGName"
```

fails to provide the resources present in a Resource Group. It needs further parameters like "ResourceID" or "ResourceName" which makes it resource specific.

What I need is that, it should return all the resources in a resource group.
Is it a bug with the newer version or am I missing something!
Suggest

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Find-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource):

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains "RGName"
```

Comment: But, it comes with a warning, saying "tagvalue" will get modified in future release. I hope this command should work in future as well.
Thanks

Comment: I believe that warning is due to the fact that `Find-AzureRmResource` has TagName and TagValue parameters, but `Find-AzureRmResourceGroup` has a Tag parameter.  They will be changing these cmdlets to work the same way.  If you're not searching by tag then your scripts will not be impacted if and when this is changed.

Answer (score 4):

The `Get-AzureRMResource` PowerShell Command is implemented from REST API. If you check the REST API of listing resources in a resource group. You will see something like this.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/resources?api-version=2015-01-01
```

And, if you add `-debug` option to `Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId <the resource id>`, you will find the REST API it's using.

```
https://management.azure.com<the resource id>?api-version=2015-01-01
```

Comparing this two REST API, you will see that the following PowerShell command will list the resources in a resource group.

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/resources"
```

I know it's tricky, but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Get-AzureRmResource | where {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq "RG"}
```

Comment: Tried to write [ODataQuery](https://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-safely-replace-find-azurermresource-resourcetype-calls-in-azure-powershell-6-x/) but then your answer simplified the problem a great deal:

`Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "\`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'" | where { $_.ResourceName.StartsWith('myappblobstorage') -and $_.ResourceGroupName -eq '$ResourceGroupNameBlob' }`

Comment: "$ResourceGroupNameBlob" (for variable)

Answer (score 3):

> Get the resource group in an object

```
$groups = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $RG_Name
```

> fetch all the resources of a resource group in a variable

```
$t=(Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameEquals 
$groups.ResourceGroupName).ResourceName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple command `Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg` to get all the resources within a Resource Group and then can loop through to perform some task.